# как открыть файл .exe через функцию python причем не указывая полный путь releaseAPP/fastcommand.exe?

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста, я уже гуглил много раз но нормального ответа не нашел,
вот кусочек кода (извиняюсь сразу, я новичек в этом)

```
def calcAPP(self):
    app_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "releaseAPP")
    os.startfile(app_path, "fastcommand.exe")
```

мне нужно открыть файл exe из папки releaseAPP которая находится вместе с main.py, при этом не указывая полный путь до файла

[image: Иерархия файлов]

Comment: укажите относительный. `releaseAPP/fastcommand.exe`. для справки о том, что такое абсолютный и относительный путь можете для начала прочитать [википедийную статью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83)

Comment: пробовал выдает ошибку файл не найден

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: '../releaseAPP/fastcommand.exe'

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'releaseAPP/fastcommand.exe'